# Rewrite classic ASP website to new technology with SQL Server database?

Tags: open-source, node.js, web-apis, angularjs, mvc

I want to rewrite a whole classic ASP website to new technology. But I don't want to change our current SQL Server database.

Which is the best new technology and language that more efficient, more secure, more robust, develop more quickly and relevant with our old classic ASP?

1. I prefer C# , MVC, JavaScript and etc.
2. Must run on all OS and mobile view.
3. Also I prefer disconnected mode.

Comment: Your question is far too broad. You give so little information about your environment that we can only tell you “pick whatever you like”. Please read our [question qualitiy guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). Also we only do software recommendations here, [not language recommendations](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36/should-programming-language-recommendations-be-allowed-here).

Comment: https://angularjs.org/

Comment: Should I use C# or JavaScript ?